# NetBeans (If statement not working)

Tags: if-statement, netbeans

When I define the if statement to be if (q==1), and another one to be if (q==2), and I type 2, it still goes to the first statement, as if I typed 1.

```
            if (u==2) {
            System.out.println("Hvad har du brug for at regne ud?");
            System.out.println("Tryk 1 og enter for stofmængde (n)");
            System.out.println("Tryk 2 og enter for molarmasse (g/mol)(M)");
            System.out.println("Tryk 3 og enter for samlet masse (m)");

            int q = tastatur.nextInt();
                if (q == 1); {

                System.out.println("Du har valgt at regne stofmængde ud");
                System.out.println("Indtast molarmasse og tryk enter");
                double molarmasse = tastatur.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Indtast samlet masse og tryk enter");
                double masse = tastatur.nextDouble();

                double stofmængde = (masse/molarmasse);

                System.out.println("Stofmængde =" +masse+ "/" +molarmasse);
                System.out.println("Stofmængden =" +stofmængde);}


                if (q == 2); {
                System.out.println("Du har valgt at regne molarmasse ud");
                System.out.println("Indtast stofmængde og tryk enter");
                double stof = tastatur.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Indtast samlet masse og tryk enter");
                double mass = tastatur.nextDouble();

                double mm = (mass/stof);

                System.out.println("Molarmasse =" +mass+ "/" +stof);
                System.out.println("Molarmasse =" +mm);}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you should remove ";" after if( ) statement. Get the value of q to check it is 1 or 2. I also suggest to use eclipse due to some sort of bugs exist in netbeans IDE.

Comment: To elaborate on this - with the `;` in there, `if (q == 1);` is treated as a statement on its own, not something that has anything to do with the curly brackets after. So it's evaluated as true or false, and then ignored. Then the stuff inside the curly brackets runs, whatever q was. :)